# Don't understand how os.path.dirname() work

Tags: python, os.path, sys.path

I'm pretty new to  the Python world and would like to know if someone can explain this line of code?

I know it adds the directory of the target file to the sys.path, but don't know how it is going on.

```
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)`?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure, since I don't know what this line of code does. The above line was taken from another stackoverflow answer about  sys.path as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start by explaining some things:

- [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__file__) is a Python built-in. It yields the absolute path of the current executing script.
- [`os.path.dirname`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) returns the directory of a given path name, e.g. if given the input `/a/b/c/d`, it would yield `/a/b/c`.
- [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) is a list of directories that Python will use to search for modules when you try to import something.

---

`os.path.dirname(__file__)` returns the parent directory of the current script being executed (i.e. `../`)

`os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))` returns the parent directory of the parent directory of the current script being executed. (i.e. `../../`)

`os.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))` will register the parent directory of the parent directory of the current executing script as a place to lookup new modules.

---

So, let's say we have the following directory structure:

```
a
|- b
|- c
|-----d
|     |----e
|     |    |---- f
|     |    |     |- main.py
|     |    |- bar.py
|     |- foo.py
|- foobar.py
```

Providing the script that contains this code is `main.py`, then the end result will be `sys.path.append('/a/d/e')`, so you'd be able to do `import bar` (but not `import foo` or `import foobar`)

Comment: Thank you! Really! With your explanation about what os.path.dirname() and __file__  actually  are, everything is clear to me now.